# list generator confusion

Tags: python, list, iterator, generator

Been reading Pep-0289. It mentions that

```
sum(x*x for x in range(10))
```

will conserve memory over this:

```
sum([x*x for x in range(10)])
```

What I'm confused about is why `range(10)` won't generate the entire list at once. Is there something where, if you throw `range()` in the for-each construction, it automatically becomes an iterator? I thought the answer was no, because that is what `xrange()` in Python 2.x is for.

Further down the Pep it says:

```
def __gen(exp):
    for x in exp:
        yield x**2
g = __gen(iter(range(10)))
print g.next()
```

Here they use `iter` to turn `range(10)` into an iterator. Why is `iter` not needed in the earlier examples? Are `[x for x in range(3)]` and `[x for x in iter(range(3))]` somehow treated the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`range(10)` will generate the entire list at once.  That's not the memory-conserving part though.

This:

```
sum(x*x for x in range(10))
```

will basically calculate (more or less) as follows:

- cur_sum = 1*1
- cur_sum = cur_sum + 2*2
- ...
- cur_sum = cur_sum + 9*9

That is it will calculate each individually, and sum as it goes along

The following:

```
sum([x*x for x in range(10)])
```

Instead will create an entire list first of:

- [1*1, 2*2, 3*3...9*9]

and then do the sum.

Answer (score 1):

> Are `[x for x in [1, 3, 4]]` and `[x for x in iter([1, 3, 4])]` somehow
>   treated the same?

They have the same effect, yes.  The line:

```
[x for x in [1, 3, 4]]
```

implicitly calls the list's [`__iter__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__) to get an iterator over it.  It is equivalent to this:

```
[x for x in [1, 3, 4].__iter__()]
```

This line however:

```
[x for x in iter([1, 3, 4])]
```

uses [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) to get an iterator over the list.  It also is equivalent to:

```
[x for x in [1, 3, 4].__iter__()]
```

except that it unnecessarily uses the built-in `iter` function to do what the `for ... in ...` clause does already.

---

A better use of `iter` is to control iteration over an iterable step-by-step.  Below is an example:

```
it = iter(iterable)
item = next(it)  # Get the first item in the iterator
while True:
    # code
    if condition:
        item = next(it)  # Advance the iterator only if condition is True
```

Comment: So I guess what I'm asking is why `sum(x*x for x in range(3))` doesn't end up as `sum(x*x for x in [1 2 3])`, with the range expanded out. I can understand if `xrange` was used instead.

Comment: @mwlow - It does actually.  The PEP was saying that `sum(x*x for x in range(10))` is more efficient than `sum([x*x for x in range(10)])` because we are using a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression) instead of a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (which makes an unnecessary list).  In both examples however, `range(10)` returns a list.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I thought the generator part was getting rid of the list in range()